# React Native Pagination and React Navigation Problem

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I am facing a complex type of problem due to pagination and React Native Navigation.
Drawer having the categories list on click they are all going to the screen

**Problem Statement:**

When I click randomly on categories every thing is working fine. But, getting the problem during pagination. Suppose I click on category Consumer and scroll for more records. After that I click on **Mobile** category. Mobile Category Page will be shown for a second and after that previous route is called (Consumer).

I tried with the following code to navigate the category but getting the same problem.

**Code:**

1).

```
this.props.navigation.navigate({
  routeName: "CategoryList",
  params: {
    cat_id: e.cat_id
  },
  key: Math.random () * 10000
})
```

2).

```
const resetAction = StackActions.reset({
  index: 0,
  actions: [NavigationActions.navigate({
    routeName: 'CategoryList',
    params: {
      cat_id: e.cat_id
    }
  })],
});
this.props.navigation.dispatch(resetAction);
```

3).

```
const pushAction = StackActions.push({
  routeName: "CategoryList",
  params: {
    cat_id: e.cat_id
  }
});
this.props.navigation.dispatch(pushAction);
```

Comment: Didn't get your point. Can you explain it with more details or by video?

Comment: @KishanVaghela In simple terms when I click load more products after loading on new products I navigate to other category e.g. Mobile. Page redirect 2 times, 1 to show mobile categories that is correct but, suddenly it redirects to previous category page e.g. http://localhost/category/1?page_no=2 but it should load the page of http://localhost/category/5 but not the previous pagination record  that is http://localhost/category/1?page_no=2.
I hope this make sense.

Comment: I think there is a problem in another part, not navigation.

Comment: Still adding a video could help.

Comment: @AshwinMothilal I can't add video. This is illegal according to my company. I am sorry I can't share video.

Comment: when you are clicking mobile/consumer category wich component/page is rendering your items ???

Comment: Maybe you can consider write a minimal example to build?

Comment: @PrakashKarena for all categories "CategoryList" component is called. Routing is working fine without load more products.
But, when I scroll and load more components and navigate to other category. After few seconds suddenly page redirects to previous category with pageno and cat_id.

Comment: when you click on perticuler category which page is called???

Comment: @PrakashKarena CategoryList page is called.

Comment: you are getting old records for second in your categorylist,am i right???

Comment: @PrakashKarena Yes. I am getting the records of previous category. If I scroll for more categories e.g I am in category A on page no 2.
After that I click on category B. Page redirect to category B. Suddenly after one more redirect it show the products of category A instead of Category B.

Comment: i'll explain you why this happen.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206040/discussion-between-vikash-dhiman-and-prakash-karena).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In categoryList page shows old items because of we have old records in our redux store so we need to assign empty array for first time by our self.So, when our page is called we are assigning empty array by our self.

```
componentWillMount = () => {
this.props.categoryListRecord.categoryList = []
}

mapStateToProps = (state) => { ....
categoryListRecord : state.categoryListReducer
```

then we can dispatch our action and get new records and use it in our component.Solve this error